# Image and data upload to database,using php

Tags: javascript, php

got this code to upload new products to the db
Since im new to php,ive got it copied from several sources
Everything seems to be on the place,and the syntax is alright,but still no success in uploading the image & inserting the data to db

UPLOAD.php page -

```
<?php
require "dbconn.php";
require "functions.php";

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

     $product_name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
     $product_price = strip_tags($_POST['price']);
     $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']);

}

$target_dir = "img/'.$category.'/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        insert_new_product($product_name, $product_price, $target_file, $category);
        header("Location: add_product.php?cname=$category");
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<table>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
<td>
<input name="name" type="text">Name:</br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="price" type="text">Price:</br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" type="hidden">
</td>

</tr>

<tr>

    Choose the file:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: your submit button is called name="submit" but you're checking for Submit if(isset($_POST['Submit'])). btw do you have any errors?

Comment: add some debug print or echo to your code to understand where is the issue.

Comment: as i said im preety new to PHP,could you tell me please how its done ?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. It's also unknown if you are using your entire code in the same file and how it's accessed as, if on local machine or hosted. Make sure those folders exist and that are writeable.

Comment: Copied the error tags,got nothing(Theres one page for the form,and one for the upload. Its hosted

Comment: add debug numeration line - something like echo "Step-1<br>"; echo "Step-2<br>"; etc before and inside the if, so you can get the right point where the application it's fails

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to change

```
$target_dir = "img/'.$category.'/";
```

to

```
$target_dir = "img/".$category."/";
```

Also, try seeing where the request is going when you submit the form. You would need a base tag ideally to specify a PHP controller as the form action without the full path.

Comment: you meen to change the action="upload.php" to what exactly ?

Comment: something like server_name:<port>/upload.php. Basically check if upload.php is accessible from the page you are trying to do this on.

Comment: they both in a same folder

Comment: Just try it. Your post form doesn't know they are in the same folder. When you reply to this, go look in the Network tab in Chrome Developer Options(press F12). This tab contains any requests being made by the page. Clear it, Post your form and then see the url for that request. If it resolves to your upload.php path with the server path and all included, we can look elsewhere for the issue. If the url is just upload.php, you need to specify a base url.

Comment: So what i nee to do is - 1)Change the action="" from ="upload.php" to ="mywebsite/upload.php" 2)On the page its taking me after submiting the form press F12 . What's the next step ? I just dont get it

Comment: press F12 before submitting.
In chrome you will see a tab called network. Click on it
Clear this using the icon at the top left corner.

Post your form. You will immediately see something added to the Network tab. This is the request your page makes when posting the form. See what url it shows

Comment: it's taking me to the upload page